# Using CMYK colorspace in PCL XL, possible?

Tags: color-space, cmyk, pclxl

Is it possible to use PCL XL to print CMYK composite halftone (1-bit) data? Or do I have to somehow convert it to 8bit RGB data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCL XL, aka PCL version 6, does not support CMYK colorspace